# Can I use a button to clear the canvas?

Tags: python, tkinter-canvas

I'm trying the clear the canvas when the "Enter" button is pressed. The canvas currently has a Label, an Entry, and the Button. I'm extremely new to Tkinter so I wouldn't be surprised if it's an easily fixable mistake.

```py
def clear():
    w.delete('all')
enter = Button(w, text = "Enter", command = clear)
enter.pack()
```

I expected the canvas to just become blank, but the label, entry, and button just stay there.

Comment: `.delete()` is only going to affect things added via the `.create_XXXX()` drawing methods - `.create_window()` is the only one that can add actual widgets as content.  Ordinary child widgets are not affected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello I think what you need is a button that calls the `pack_forget()` method:

```
enter = Button(w, text = 'Enter', command = lambda: '#your_canvas_name'.pack_forget())
```

`#your_canvas_name` is the name you assigned to your canvass widget.

Hope this helps :))